# React Hooks ( usestate ) not printing initial value

Tags: react-hooks

In React, when using useState() hook then why its initial value is printed as [object Object ] rather than the given initial value.

I tried to use the JSON.stringify to get the real value but then also its shows only [object Object] value on screen

Comment: Can you please provide related code blocks?

Comment: Thanks, But I get resolved my issue it was the problem in rendering the props which shows [object, Object] but when I put. [ for example :-  myprop.property] then it render it correctly.

Answer (score 1):

This happens because React treats objects and arrays differently when they are converted to strings for display purposes. The default conversion of an object to a string, when directly used in JSX, results in the [object Object] string representation.

Comment: Yes absolutely. Thanks for taking the time to explain the issue.